# Why does Socket.connect uses a SocketAddress rather than a InetSocketAddress?

Tags: java, sockets

Why does `Socket.connect` uses a SocketAddress rather than a InetSocketAddress?
I read the source code of `Socket.connect`, it just cast a `SocketAddress` to a `InetSocketAddress`, and it throws a `IllegalArgumentException` if the `SocketAddress` could not cast to a `InetSocketAddress`.
I am very confused about the significance of this.

Comment: Because `Socket.connect` is generic and shared for many different types of connections and address-types?

Comment: @SomeprogrammerdudeI understand a little, it is write for scalability right?

Comment: Not scalability, but *generalization*. There are many more network types than TCP/IP and their IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Many of these network types can use sockets, but need other types of addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea might be that future versions of Socket class can support other types of connections.